# Aggregation function optimization

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

i have a data set named customer_base, containing over 800K rows like below:

| ID | AGE | GENDER | OCCUPATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 64 | 101 | "occ1" |
| 2 | 64 | 100 | "occ2" |
| 2 | 66 | 100 | Nan |
| 2 | Nan | 100 | "occ2" |
| 3 | Nan | 101 | "occ3" |
| 3 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 3 | 32 | Nan | Nan |
| . | . | . | . |

and after a grouping operation the desired version of it should be like below:

| ID | AGE | GENDER | OCCUPATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 64 | 101 | "occ1" |
| 2 | 66 | 100 | "occ2" |
| 3 | 32 | 101 | "occ3" |
| . | . | . | . |

previously i tried a code sample like below to get a table as clean as possible, but it took too much time. now i need a faster function to get any of the available values of `occupation` column.

```
customer_base.groupby("ID",
                      as_index=False).agg({"GENDER":"max",                                                              
                                           "AGE":"max",
                                           "OCCUPATION":lambda x: np.nan if len(x[x.notna()])==0 else x[x.notna()].values[0]})
```

thanks in advance for your optimization ideas, sorry for possible question duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non `NaN`s values:

```
df = customer_base.groupby("ID", as_index=False).agg({"AGE":"max",
                                                      "GENDER":"max",
                                                      "OCCUPATION":'first'})

print (df)
   ID   AGE  GENDER OCCUPATION
0   1  64.0   101.0     "occ1"
1   2  66.0   100.0     "occ2"
2   3  32.0   101.0     "occ3"
```

Comment: Thank you, for the fastest and the simplest. and the the first :)